# Remove default routes only for default module in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, routes, zend-route

I have 2 modules: default and admin.

For default module I created custom and removed default routes because I don't want my web works with booth (custom and default).
But I want to use default routes for admin module.

Can I set default routes only for one module ?
how to do this in Zend Framework ?

If I set

$router->removeDefaultRoutes();

in bootstrap, my routes doesn't work for admin module.
I use one Bootstrap.php file for booth modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check current module:

```
if (Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getModuleName() == 'default') {
    $router->removeDefaultRoutes();
}
```

Comment: You can also overwrite the default route.

Comment: Since the routing process is what determines the current module I'm not sure how this would work.

Comment: @tasmaniski - What do you mean by 'better'? garvey's solution seems as straightforward as you can get in Zend.

Comment: @Mike If you think this is good answer why you didn't upvote ?? 
I mean without if() condition... garvey's solutions is good enough so approve and upvote from me.

Comment: @tasmaniski I was not able to test garvey's solution, so I am not going to upvote it. I am not trying to be snarky, I am only pointing out that, if it works, garvey's solution looks very clean and readable.